# Split on a space or line break

Tags: c#

I'm using a data capture software (PSI-Capture) that uses C# scripting. I need to know the best way to convert a captured value to a string and then split on a space or line break character. I'm capturing a full name field (FirstName MiddleName Surname) and sometimes they are in one line or two lines. So I need to split on both spaces and line breaks so I can populate each part of the name in a separate field.

The names are sometimes like that in one line:

> MICHAEL JACKSON

And sometimes they are like that in two lines:

> MICHAEL JAMES
>   JACKSON

Comment: Have you tried `s.Split(new[] { '\n', '\r', ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `NewLine` with `space` and `split` on basis of `space`

```
string str = str.Replace(Environment.NewLine," ");
string[] array = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Use of `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` will ensure that no `empty entries` remain in `array`

Comment: My scripting skills are very limited as I'm still learning them, I ended up with this but there must be something wrong with it as I can't get it work

Comment: if(dataField.Name == "Z_Name")
      {
         try
         {
         string str = str.Replace(Environment.NewLine," ");
     string[] array = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

     string  actualName = Regex.Replace(Z_Name, @"\r\n?|\n|\s+", "-");
     string[] nm = actualName.Split(new char[]{'-'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     firstname = nm[0];
     if(nm.Length > 2)
      {
        middlename = nm[1];
        lastname = nm[2];
      }
     else
      {
        lastname = nm[1];
      }
     }
    }

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
names = names.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " "); // as suggested by @Dmitry Bychenko
string[] nm = names.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

now if the `string[] nm` contains 2 elements that means the name doesnt have the middle name so

```
firstname = nm[0];
if(nm.Length > 2)
{
    middlename = nm[1];
    lastname = nm[2]
}
else 
{
    lastname = nm[1]
}
```

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` instead of `"\r\n"` is more accurate implementation

Comment: Please change `nm.Length>=2` to `nm.Length>2`. If `nm` contains 2 elements `nm[2]` will throw an excepton.

Comment: Nice catch @erikscandola. Done. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Let `nameInputText` be the user input then you can try the following for getting the required array of user name parts:

```
string  actualName = Regex.Replace(nameInputText, @"\r\n?|\n|\s+", "-");
string[] partsOfName = actualName.Split(new char[]{'-'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Here in this example, you will get `MICHAEL-JAMES-JACKSON` in `actualName` variable and by splitting based on `-` will gives you the required array of elements, the parts of the name